# Grouping a dataframe by one column and adding information based on the column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                   2:["a","a","x","b","b","y","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"],
                   3:[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10,0.11,0.13,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17]})
```

```
    1  2     3
0   1  a  0.50
1   1  a  0.60
2   1  x  0.70
3   2  b  0.80
4   2  b  0.90
5   2  y  0.10
6   3  c  0.11
7   4  d  0.13
8   5  e  0.13
9   6  f  0.14
10  7  g  0.15
11  8  h  0.16
12  9  i  0.17
```

I want to:

1. Group the items by the first column so that it's comprised of unique values.
2. Attach the mean of the third column to this grouping.
3. Attach the second column's information to each corresponding first column's.

I can do (1) and (2) with the following method:

```
In [33]: df.groupby(1).mean()
Out[33]: 
      3
1      
1  0.60
2  0.60
3  0.11
4  0.13
5  0.13
6  0.14
7  0.15
8  0.16
9  0.17
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about attaching the second column to the grouping.

I've tried grouping by multiple columns:

```
In [34]: df.groupby([1,2]).mean()
Out[34]: 
        3
1 2      
1 a  0.55
  x  0.70
2 b  0.60
3 c  0.11
4 d  0.13
5 e  0.13
6 f  0.14
7 g  0.15
8 h  0.16
9 i  0.17
```

But in the actual dataset it leaves out several entries.

If you notice, within the dataframe there are some differences in the 2nd column data for each entry (Number 1 under column 1 has 2 "a's" and an "x", and number 2 has 2 "b's" and a "y"). This is because in the actual dataset there are minute differences between the entries due to errors and slight (but insignificant) differences in the string data.

**Edit**

The above is just a conceptual presentation of the problem. If you need something more tangible, [this is the dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t2co9LM1TnESIHHRCM5n6sOGHp0EJvBmD93gejKTjEA/edit?usp=sharing). I want to group by the `"CUSTOMERS NAME"` and `"CUSTOMER ADDRESS"` columns while finding the mean, but grouping by the two of them simultaneously leads to a loss in entries for some reason. If I group purely by `"CUSTOMER NAME"` then there are a little over 4300 entries.

```
In [35]: len(ensemble.("CUSTOMERS NAME").mean())
Out[35]: 4376
```

But if I group by both name and address it falls substantially:

```
In [36]: len(ensemble.groupby(["CUSTOMERS NAME","CUSTOMER ADDRESS"]).mean())
Out[36]: 4154
```

I know something's wrong somewhere because the total number of unique values in the `"CUSTOMERS NAME"` columns is 4376.

For clarification, the output should be a dataframe with three columns. The first is the name of the customer, the second is the address attached to the customer's name (the first is fine), the third is the mean of that customer's transactions.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Once you groupby, there will be just one entry per group. So you can't simply attach 2nd column values just like that. You can create a list of 2nd col values for every group and attach it to the grouped df.

Comment: @MayankPorwal it should be a dataframe with three columns. The first is the name of the customer, the second is the address attached to the customer's name (the first is fine), the third is the mean of that customer's transactions.

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `first` value from `2` col is fine, you can use [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [583]: x = df.groupby(1, as_index=False).agg({2:'first', 3:'mean'})

In [584]: x
Out[584]: 
   1  2     3
0  1  a  0.60
1  2  b  0.60
2  3  c  0.11
3  4  d  0.13
4  5  e  0.13
5  6  f  0.14
6  7  g  0.15
7  8  h  0.16
8  9  I  0.17
```

**OR**, if you want all values, you can have a list:

```
In [586]: x = df.groupby(1, as_index=False).agg({2: list, 3:'mean'})

In [587]: x
Out[587]: 
   1          2     3
0  1  [a, a, x]  0.60
1  2  [b, b, y]  0.60
2  3        [c]  0.11
3  4        [d]  0.13
4  5        [e]  0.13
5  6        [f]  0.14
6  7        [g]  0.15
7  8        [h]  0.16
8  9        [i]  0.17
```